# Laravel Eloquent Query works on controller but Blade also fails

Tags: laravel, object, eloquent, laravel-blade, belongs-to

There are two models,

**User**

id, name, surname, email, etc.

**Comment**

id, user_id, comment, etc.

```
Comment Model


public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

I can get the user's email address when I try the controller with the following query

```
$comments = Comment::where('status',1)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
foreach ($comments  as $comment){

    return $comment->user->email;
}
```

However, what I did not succeeded, I get an error when I write the following to the Blade file.

```
@foreach($comments as  $comment)

                                <a href="{{ $comment->user->email }}">
                                    <img class="avatar" src="{{ $comment->user->photo }}"
                                         data-at2x="{{ $comment->user->photo }}"
                                         alt="{{ $comment->user->slug}}">
                                </a>

                        @endforeach
```

> Error Message : Trying to get property of non-object

I am waiting for your help, thanks in advance.

Comment: did you dump `$comments` in your blade?

Comment: yes dump i can see the comments, there is no problem at that point. I do not get an error even if I made $ comment-> user. But I get an error when I type $ comment-> user-> email. Laravel Version 5.6 by the way.

Comment: are you sure that `$comment-> user` is not null for each iteration? if so, check the rest of code, problem might be somewhere else

Comment: I'm sure it's not null. Here I dump

Comment: Comment{#588 ▼
  #table: "comments"
  
  +incrementing: true
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:12 [▼
    "id" => 2625
    "comment" => "soru 24 deki d ve c seceneğinin ikisi de doğru değil mi"
    "tur" => 2
    "icerik" => 19036
    "yorum_cevap_id" => 0
    "user_id" => 9030
    "email" => ""
    "kullanici" => ""
    "ip" => "79.123.238.111"
    "onay" => 1
    "created_at" => "2017-11-22 06:24:34"
    "updated_at" => "2017-11-22 20:21:55"

Comment: You need to do it with `$comment->user()->email`

Comment: you didn't get the error in controller because you iterate only once, also its not good idea to do database calls in loop. try to retrieve your data like `Comment::with('user')->where('status',1)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get()` and then check if each comment has user

Comment: I did what you said, but I made a mistake    Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$email

Comment: In the future, providing the entire contents of your Controller method and Blade file will include more context and make answering your question easier for other people. Including just a snippet can mistakenly leave out crucial details.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment Model add `with` field

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $with = [
        'user'
    ];
    protected $fillable = [
       ....
    ];

    public function user (){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User'  ,'user_id' ,'id' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not happen

Comment: @ersen check this if not worked please send var_dump one comment

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using Lazy Eager `with`

```
$comments = Comment::with('user')->where('status',1)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
 return view('YourViewPath/ViewFileName.blade.php',compact('comments'));
```

now in your view:

```
@foreach($comments as  $comment)

       <a href="{{ $comment->user->email }}">
            <img class="avatar" src="{{ $comment->user->photo }}"
                 data-at2x="{{ $comment->user->photo }}"
                 alt="{{ $comment->user->slug}}">
       </a>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a condition.

```
@foreach($comments as  $comment)
    <a href="{{ $comment->user->email?$comment->user->email:'' }}">
       <img class="avatar" 
           src="{{ $comment->user->photo?$comment->user->photo }}" 
           data-at2x="{{ $comment->user->photo }}"
           alt="{{ $comment->user->slug?$comment->user->slug:''}}">
    </a>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for your frustration. More precisely, at http://forum.laravel.gen.tr/viewtopic.php?pid=12477#p12477 @mgsmus replied to my friend.

Briefly, I need to explain; Some commenters are not in the user table.

Suggested 2 ways to Prevent this.
First;
If you are getting a try-to-get property of a non-object error, then one of the comments does not have a record associated with any User model, ie one of them is null.
In such cases you can use the optional () helper function. (Laravel is available in 5.5 and 5.6 but can also be easily passed into 5.4.) The optional () helper function allows the property to return null if the object is null, without error, instead of a non-object error.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-optional

So instead of $ comment-> user-> email in the blade, type optional ($ comment-> user) -> email. Others are optional ($ comment-> news) -> link and optional (optional ($ comment-> exam) -> link, so you will see which record is not linked.

The other way is to only keep records that have only an association:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships (Querying Relationship Existence section)

// has ('user') to make sure that we have 5 comments with the User.
// This is different from whereNotNull ('user_id') because it checks whether the has model really is. user_id may be full but we do not know it is a User with id.

```
Comment :: has ('user') -> where ('check', 1) -> orderBy ('id', 'desc') -> take (5) -> get ();
```